# Facebook: App Access token, Posting to a User

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I went through this wonderfull tutorial on [Using App Access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/). According to this post it says that:

> If the user has not provided the appropriate permissions to publish on the user’s behalf, you will receive an error message. For example, if the user has not provided the publish_stream permission, the following error will be returned:
>   {
>     "error": {
>       "message": "(#200) The user has not granted the application the permission to automatically publish feed stories", 
>       "type": "OAuthException", 
>       "code": 200
>     }
>   }

Now is there any other way to post to a users wall who has not authorized the app?

My query is this:
I have two logins for my app, one Login with Email and other FB Connection. So a user may login with email or facebook to my app. If he logs in with facebook there is no problem at all as i have his access token. If he login with email , then i don't have his user access token, so in this case i want to use the App Access token to fetch the users friends and then allow him to post to friends wall [friends who are not a member of our app / not authorized our app].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way to post to a user wall who has not authorized the app.

one possible soln:

- you have to link up the user login via the email and fbID
- stored the access token when the user accesses your app via fbID
- if the user login via the email, then get the access token from local storage and use it for the posting.